# Is it possible to dynamically specify the file name at runtime in a COBOL program?

Tags: cobol

Is it possible to dynamically specify the file name at runtime in a COBOL program?

For example I would like to not have to define the name of a file I would like to open when I write the File-Control section, I would like to read the name of the file I want to open from a different file containing names and I would also like to define(FD) the file I want to open when I pass the name to File-COntrol.

The platform is Unix with Micro Focus Visual Cobol compiler.

Comment: is this an IBM mainframe? we have a solution for dynamic file allocation using the BPXWDYN program.

Comment: Please note the platform. IBM mainframe is different from other platforms. For example, PC/Unix have the ability to specify a WORKING-STORAGE item through the FILE ID clause of the SELECT statement. In IBM mainframe, there are also issues regarding FDs in this scenario.

Comment: I believe the method I described in my previous comment with FILE-ID is available in MicroFocus. If you have access to the documentation, I recommend you look there.

Answer (score 1):

I really love it when people ask for help posting a snippet of code that doesn't have a prayer of compiling.

```
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.

PROGRAM-ID.     STACK-OVERFLOW-1.
AUTHOR.         Roland Hughes.
DATE-WRITTEN.   TODAY.
DATE-COMPILED.  TODAY.

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.

  FILE-CONTROL.
      SELECT OPTIONAL OUT_FILE
          ASSIGN TO DISK
          ORGANIZATION IS SEQUENTIAL
          ACCESS MODE IS SEQUENTIAL
          FILE STATUS IS IN-STAT.

DATA DIVISION.

FILE SECTION.
  FD OUT_FILE
     IS GLOBAL
     VALUE OF FILE-ID IS OUT_FILE_NAME
     LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.

    01 DTL-LINE.
      03 FIELDA      PIC X(14).
      03 FIELDB      PIC X(10).
      03 FIELDC      PIC X(32).
      03 FIELDD      PIC X(03).
      03 FIELDE      PIC X(02).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
    01 STATUS-VARIABLES.
       05 IN-STAT           PIC X(2).

    01 STUFF.
       05 OUT_FILE_NAME     PIC X(80).

PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
    MOVE "FILE1.DAT" to OUT_FILE_NAME.
    OPEN OUTPUT OUT_FILE.
    MOVE SPACES TO DTL-LINE.
    MOVE 'HELLO!' TO FIELDA.
    WRITE DTL-LINE.
    CLOSE OUT_FILE

    MOVE "FILE2.DAT" to OUT_FILE_NAME.
    OPEN OUTPUT OUT_FILE.
    MOVE SPACES TO DTL-LINE.
    MOVE 'HI!' TO FIELDB.
    WRITE DTL-LINE.
    CLOSE OUT_FILE.

    MOVE "FILE3.DAT" to OUT_FILE_NAME.
    OPEN OUTPUT OUT_FILE.
    MOVE SPACES TO DTL-LINE.
    MOVE 'FRED' TO FIELDC.
    WRITE DTL-LINE.
    CLOSE OUT_FILE.
STOP RUN.
```

I tested this on KDE Neon with all of the latest updates installed. I installed the open-cobol package from the repositories.

```
cobc -x -free STACK-OVERFLOW-1.COB 
./STACK-OVERFLOW-1 

roland@roland-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:~/COBOL$ ls *.DAT
FILE1.DAT  FILE2.DAT  FILE3.DAT
roland@roland-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:~/COBOL$ cat *.DAT
HELLO!                                                                     HI!                                                                    FRED                                 roland@roland-HP-EliteDesk-800-G2-SFF:~/COBOL$
```

Comment: Please help: is "OPTIONAL" AND "IS GLOBAL" mandatory in this case?

Comment: Go here: https://eisner.decus.org/
Follow the bouncing ball with a good VT-320 terminal emulator and get an account.
Take the source code I provided and experiment. You can get a free account
on a real OS and test with a real commercial COBOL compiler.

OPTIONAL is required to dynamically name at least on every platform I've worked.
Has something to do with the under-the-hood startup verification code we never seek.

Comment: GLOBAL has different rules everywhere.

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/developer-for-zos/9.1.1?topic=entries-global-clause

Page 5-70 here:
https://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/kyang/2007/Fall/CMPS401/Doc/aa-q2g0h-tk.pdf

Each global sequential file becomes a print format file.

Primarily it allows programs in the same run unit to access the FD. For some platforms it also forces print format. 
There are other oddities as well. I needed it to force print format.

Answer (score 0):

A more complete example:

```
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
  FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT IN_FILE ASSIGN TO IN_FILE
     ORGANIZATION     IS SEQUENTIAL
     ACCESS MODE      IS SEQUENTIAL
     FILE STATUS      IS FSTAT.
FILE SECTION.
  FD IN_FILE
  VALUE OF ID IS IN_FILE_NAME.
    01 IN_POST.
      03 FIELDA      PIC X(14).
      03 FIELDB      PIC X(10).
      03 FIELDC      PIC X(32).
      03 FIELDD      PIC X(03).
      03 FIELDE      PIC X(02).

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  01 IN_FILE_NAME PIC X(22).
  01 FSTAT PIC XX.


PROCEDURE DIVISION. 
    MOVE "FILE1.DAT" to IN_FILE_NAME
    OPEN INPUT IN_FILE
    CLOSE IN_FILE

    MOVE "FILE2.DAT" to IN_FILE_NAME
    OPEN INPUT IN_FILE
    CLOSE IN_FILE

    MOVE "FILE3.DAT" to IN_FILE_NAME
    OPEN INPUT IN_FILE
    CLOSE IN_FILE
STOP RUN.
```

Comment: Don't you have to have the ORGANIZATION of the file, and the ACCESS MODE? DO you have a definition of IN_FILE?

Comment: Added a more complete example

Comment: Is it possible to make the FD field more general, would I be able to open the same file with for example:
FD IN_FILE
01 IN_POST PIC X(80). 
Instead of the FD you have written?

Comment: As a general rule, you never want to put a data description on an 01 level.